# solana Validator logs are not coming up

Tags: solana, solana-cli

None of the Option work to enable the Solana logs are runtime

```
 solana-validator --ledger /solana/ledger set-log-filter solana=info,solana_streamer::streamer=warn
```

```
 solana-validator --ledger /solana/ledger set-log-filter solana=debug,solana_streamer::streamer=warn
```

```
 solana-validator --ledger /solana/ledger set-log-filter solana=info
```

```
 solana-validator --ledger /solana/ledger set-log-filter solana=debug
```

The Rust Logs setting

`RUST_LOG=solana=info,solana_streamer::streamer=warn`

**Solana-validator version**

```
$ solana-validator -h
solana-validator 1.9.18 (src:devbuild; feat:1070292356)
Blockchain, Rebuilt for Scale
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68870628/how-do-i-set-up-the-logging-for-solana-test-validator/68959948#68959948

Answer (score 1):

if you want to see Stream transaction logs
you need to run `solana logs`